# Is there any tool which can generate a report for a valid C program

Tags: c, parsing, report

Is there any tool that can parse a valid **C** program and generate a report which contains list of *functions*, *global variables*, *`#define` constants*, *local variables in each function*, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doxygen does all of the above.

Comment: Thank you very much i tried it. its really good tool very helpful

Comment: Doxygen works best when you put specially-formatted comments in your code, usually with your function declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Try exuberant-ctags with the -x option and tell it to generate all of its kinds.
Exuberant CTAGS is the default ctags on many linux distros.

You might try:  exuberant-ctags -x --c-kinds=cdefglmnpstuvx --language-force=c filename

will even work if filename doesn't have .c extension.

You can use exuberant-ctags --list-kinds=c to see the possible tags.

Under windows, the cygwin environment supports ctags.  I'm not sure if there's a windows build that doesn't need cygwin.

Comment: This one is equally good. It has support for many languages which is a plus point. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a few tools, depending on what you want to do. I'm not sure what you mean by "report", things like [lxr](http://lxr.linux.no/) will do html etc. cross referenced links. But for a person to use to help understand some code, then [ncc](http://students.ceid.upatras.gr/~sxanth/ncc/) or [cscope](http://freshmeat.net/projects/cscope/) (the later of which is in most Linux distributions) also some of the IDEs have some of these features (like eclipse).
 Older alternatives to cscope are ctags and etags.

Comment: cscope isn't newer than exuberant-ctags, but cscope is very much worth the mention because it, unlike ctags, find call graph info.  The "flexible parsing" in cscope is even workable to some extent in C++ code (I use vim+exuberant ctags+cscope to edit code and it works very well).